# Center MoPub baner on SurfaceView

Tags: android, layout, surfaceview, mopub

I'd like add MoPub ad in my Android game. Game is created on SurfaceView Class. I have no xml layout file. The problem is that I can't center ad on screen. I try center and gravity everything. Still doesn't work. MoPubView extends FrameLayout.

```
    MoPubView mAdView = new MoPubView(this);
    mAdView.setAdUnitId("_MY__ID_"); 
    mAdView.loadAd();

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

    RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    mRelativeLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    mRelativeLayout.addView(mSurface);
    mRelativeLayout.addView(mAdView, layoutParams);

    mRelativeLayout.invalidate();
    setContentView(mRelativeLayout);
```

Please advise me something because it drawing me crazy. I feel I'm missing something easy.

Answer (score 1):

You can't center the content directly in MoPub, or at least I haven't found a way to do so. It's based on FrameLayout.

You have to center the ad in HTML. If you are using custom HTML code inside your MoPub campaign, just wrap the code inside `<div style="text-align:center">...</div>`. (Do this through the MoPub administration web). It solved my problem, I was using an OpenX ad provider.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a container layout with "FILL_PARENT" parameters and add your ad view into it like this:

```
MoPubView mAdView = new MoPubView(this);
mAdView.setAdUnitId(XXXXXXX);

RelativeLayout adContainer = new RelativeLayout(this);
addContentView(adContainer, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

LayoutParams adParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 1); //to align vertically at top
adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, 1); //to align horizontally at center

adContainer.addView(mAdView, adParams);
mAdView.loadAd();
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not good idea to set constant banner width but as long as your banners are 320px it works fine:

```
final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

MoPubView mAdView = new MoPubView(this);
mAdView.setAdUnitId(MOPUB_ID); 
mAdView.loadAd();

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int) (320*scale), LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);

mRelativeLayout.addView(mSurface);
mRelativeLayout.addView(mAdView, layoutParams);

mRelativeLayout.invalidate();
setContentView(mRelativeLayout);
```

Comment: Bonus points for using density as scale. Makes a huge difference on some devices with scale factor of 1.5

Answer (score 0):

I have done same thing with below code snippet.I am using LibGDX java game engine.

```
Relativelayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
                adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

                moPubView = new MoPubView(mActivity.getApplicationContext());
                moPubView.setAdUnitId("XXXXXX");// Banner test Ad unit Id.
                moPubView.setAutorefreshEnabled(true);
                moPubView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                layout.addView(moPubView,adParams);
```

1.I have Relative layout in parent.

2.Added MoPubView in the parent Relative layout with layoutParams only **ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM** && **CENTER_HORIZONTAL**

```
layout.addView(moPubView,adParams);
```